# VSC will recreate entire Python environment for Azure Functions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am writing some Python-based Azure Functions on Visual Studio Code. Everytime I have made changes and click the Deploy button, the code first runs locally, re-downloads all required libraries, then fails saying that the path does not exists. Isn't there a better way to go about this dev process ?

I tried removing the function from Azure Portal and then it would work upon recreation but I can't keep doing this.

Error Message: Failed to deploy path that does not exist

Comment: You could try deploy with the cli command.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#deploy-the-function-app-project-to-azure

Comment: Sounds like there may be a bug here as well. I’d recommend using the VS Code report a bug tool on the Azure Functions extension and include any relevant info - may help. In meantime cli is a good idea for mitigation